Is symptotic the antonym of asymptotic in the context of computer science?
In computer science, asymptotic analysis1 is the study of the performance of an algorithm with respect to the size of the input as the input grows to infinity.
That is to say, it only analyses how performance changes as the input grows, and only for large inputs.
In this way, one can say, for example, that appending an item at the end of a linked list has a constant, or O(1) cost, meaning that no matter how large the list, it takes the same amount of time to add one more item. Similarly, appending to an array list takes amortised constant, or amortised O(1) time, in that any given operation might have a cost proportional to the size of the list, if the backing array is full and the contents must be copied onto a larger one in order to accomodate the extra element, but the size of the array is chosen such that the cost of the copy is amortised to a constant value over all the insertions until the next copy is necessary (typically doubling the size at every copy, meaning that there is one element insertion for each element copy).
This is all well and good, but sometimes one is interested in the cost of an algorithm at small sizes of the input, or cares about the constant factor, which is ignored in asymptotic analysis (algorithm which take 100s or 1s regardless of input size
are both O(1)). It is true that these factors diminish to irrelevancy at sufficiently large scale, but there is nonetheless value in discussing the behavior of an algorithm non-asymptotically. For example, as explained above, linked lists and array lists both have asymptotic insertion costs of (amortised) O(1), and so in choosing one of the two, one might consider the symptotic (?) efficiency instead.
Now the question is what to call such an analysis. The obvious answer appears to be symptotic, but while that might be etymologicaly correct, I question whether it can really be used as such in this context.
Dictionaries don't seem to feature this meaning of the word. On the other hand, I'm relatively confident that most programmers familiar with asymptotic analysis would understand the meaning of a sentence containing the phrase "symptotic analysis" easily enough, and etymologically, asymptotic is an antonym of symptotic (from which it should follow that the reverse is true too).
Usage statistics of the two words are completely disproportionate, with the usage of symptotic being roughly 3 orders of magnitude less than that of asymptotic, however, comparing the statistics of symptotic and asymptotic shows that their usage follows the same evolution (when one rose in popularity so did the other and when one fell out of use the other declined too). This suggests that the words are semantically linked. Then again, it could also be explained by the predominant use of symptotic being as a misspelling of asymptotic.

1The linked article explains the general concept as mathematically formulated. A better article for its application to computer science in particular is Big O Notation
P.S. I wasn't sure whether this question belongs most to ELL.SE, english.SE or SO. I can see a case for any of them. Feel free to correct me if I chose poorly.
P.P.S. What comes first, postscripts or footnotes? Tell me in the comments if there's an accepted convention.

If you want to know what computer scientists call it, https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is almost certainly a better place to ask. Asymptotic is sufficiently divorced from the original Greek meaning "not falling together" that I don't think it makes much sense to return to the root or remove the a-.

As a professional programmer for over 40 years, I've never heard the term "symptotic".

As Stuart says, if you want to know what computer scientists call it, ComputerScience.SE is the place to ask. Subject-specific language often has different stipulative definitions and phraseology from everyday English, and ELU deals mainly with general usage.
